# Cannot parse WSDL - No such file or directory

Tags: java, web-services, web, soap, wsdl

I am testing SOAP with java. I have created a web service interface and its implementation. Now I want to generate the interface class with wsimport. I go to `/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/bin` and write `./wsimport -keep http://localhost:8080/Brain_war/DataImpl?wsdl` (if I go to the specified url with hand, it gives the correct xml). This run gives the following error log:

> parsing WSDL...
>
> Generating code...
>
> [ERROR] ./service/Data.java (No such file or directory)

Any suggestions ? (The Data.java file actually is the interface of web service and it is located in service package.)

Comment: It does not look like problem with WSDL location. How about to give `wsimport` target directory where to place generated code through `-d <directory>` and `-s <directory>` options? I suspect that you have no proper permissions to write into `/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/bin`... BTW why to do not use Maven plugin to do that?

Comment: @Vadim worked for me, answer please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK it seems I was right...

by default `wsimport` tries to put generated files into current directory and if user does not have proper rights files are not saved.

So, for `wsimport` it is better to always define directories where to place generated code through `-d <directory>` and `-s <directory>` options